# r transform dataset from long to wide

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I am dealing with a dataset which is in a long format as shown below.

```
  id      Name                 FluidTotal
  60718   Rocuronium           11.069175
  07860   Rocuronium           5.967500
  90389   Rocuronium           200.000000
  01536   Rocuronium           78.311333 
  01536   Rocuronium           51.415600 
  28047   Rocuronium           72.944444
  28047   Acid                 1
  28047   Acid                 1
  28047   Acid                 1
  28047   Acid                 1
  92323   Acid                 1
  92323   Void                 100
  01536   Void                 25
  60718   Void                 70
  60718   Void                 40
```

What I am trying to do is transform this to a wide format like this below

```
   Id      Rocuronium   Acid    Void
   60718   11.069175    -       110 
   07860   5.967500     -       -                                         
   90389   200.000000   -       -
   01536   129.72693    -       25
   28047   72.944444    4       -
   92323   -            1       100
```

The first row is `60718   11.069175    -       110` ,  the cell value for `Void` is `110` because the last two rows for id `60718` in the long format are `70` and `40` so when they are converted to wide format these two values are added.

Similarly the value of `Rocuronium` for id `01536` in wide format is `129.72693` because rows 4 and 5 in the long format for this id `01536` are `78.311333` and `51.415600`

I'd appreciate any assistance on accomplishing this transformation, thanks in advance..

Comment: Essentially the same as here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424064/converting-long-to-wide-format/35424289 - just replace `min` with `sum` instead - `reshape(aggregate(FluidTotal ~ ., data=dat, FUN=sum), idvar="id", timevar="Name", direction="wide")`

Comment: Or, you can use `tidyr` package's `spread` function.

Comment: `reshape(aggregate( ....))` seems a prescription for a one time success and later failure for a new R user. Most experienced R users still have trouble with `reshape`.

Comment: @42- I really don't understand the widespread troubles with `reshape`. Anyway, `tapply` is a neat solution too, but it also loses the `id` column to a `row.name`, which will probably cause grief for a beginner too.

Comment: Perhaps you are the unique person who can read the `reshape` help page and figure out which parameters to use for the wide to long transformation and which parameters to use for the long to wide. I usually give up after my 4th or 5th failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base function `tapply` function lets you do operations within cross-classified categories:

```
with( dat, tapply( FluidTotal, list(id,Name), sum))

      Acid Rocuronium Void
1536    NA  129.72693   25
7860    NA    5.96750   NA
28047    4   72.94444   NA
60718   NA   11.06917  110
90389   NA  200.00000   NA
92323    1         NA  100
```

In describing transformations, the act of collapsing individual rows is different than just going from long to wide. It should probably be noted that this retrunes an R-matrix object and if it needed to be in the form of a dataframe you could use `data.frame` to coerce it.

Comment: Did not know if you saw it. Did not want to silently delete without acknowledging. I will delete as it is not relevant to the topic. Thank you.

Comment: @42- , latemail,  and Gopala, that is so neat. I will test other solutions as well

Answer (score 2):

We can use `xtabs` (another `base R` function).  By default, `xtabs` aggregate the `sum`.

```
xtabs(FluidTotal~., df1)
#         Name
#id          Acid Rocuronium      Void
# 1536    0.00000  129.72693  25.00000
# 7860    0.00000    5.96750   0.00000
# 28047   4.00000   72.94444   0.00000
# 60718   0.00000   11.06917 110.00000
# 90389   0.00000  200.00000   0.00000
# 92323   1.00000    0.00000 100.00000
```

Comment: By default? That's really the only option for `xtabs`. It's really `else if (NCOL(y) == 1L) {
            tapply(y, by, sum)}`

Comment: Yes, It is the only option,