# Reshaping from wide to long data while collapsing variable values for same IDs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, melt

I am relatively new to R. I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this, where PMID is an ID:

```
PMID          Variable         Value
1             MH               Humans
1             MH               Male
1             MH               Middle Aged
1             RN               Aldosterone
1             RN               Renin
2             MH               Accidents, Traffic
2             MH               Male
2             RN               Antivenins
3             MH               Humans
3             MH               Crotulus
3             MH               Young Adult
```

and so on. As you can see, some IDs have multiple MHs and/or RNs and some have none or one. I want to collapse all entries for each variable for each PMID. I also want to be able to separate each entry with a comma once collapsed, but first substitute the spaces present in the above dataframe into `_` so that I can retain each value so that my final dataframe looks like this:

```
PMID         MH                                 RN
1            Humans, Male, Middle_Aged          Aldosterone, Renin
2            Accidents,_Traffic, Male           Antivenins
3            Humans, Crotulus, Young_Adult
```

I have over 5 million rows, so please help in making the code computationally efficient. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Essentially the same procedure as - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424064/converting-long-to-wide-format/35424289 -  `aggregate` by `paste(..., collapse=",")` instead of `min`, then reshape wide on the collapsed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution, using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d <- read.table(
text='PMID;Variable;Value
1;MH;Humans
1;MH;Male
1;MH;Middle Aged
1;RN;Aldosterone
1;RN;Renin
2;MH;Accidents, Traffic
2;MH;Male
2;RN;Antivenins
3;MH;Humans
3;MH;Crotulus
3;MH;Young Adult', 
header=TRUE, sep=';', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d %>% 
  group_by(PMID, Variable) %>% 
  summarise(Value=paste(gsub(' ', '_', Value), collapse=', ')) %>% 
  spread(Variable, Value)


## Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
## Groups: PMID [3]
## 
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##    PMID                            MH                  RN
## * <int>                         <chr>               <chr>
## 1     1     Humans, Male, Middle_Aged  Aldosterone, Renin
## 2     2      Accidents,_Traffic, Male          Antivenins
## 3     3 Humans, Crotulus, Young_Adult                <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
library(reshape2)
df=ddply(df,.(PMID,Variable), summarise,Pri = paste(Value,collapse=","))
acast(df, PMID ~ Variable)

  MH                           RN                 
1 "Humans,Male,MiddleAged"     "Aldosterone,Renin"
2 "Accidentstraffic,Male"      "Antivenins"       
3 "Humans,Crotulus,YoungAdult" NA
```

Answer (score 0):

As the OP is asking for an efficient solution due to the size of the production data set of over 5 M rows, I suggest to use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
setDT(df)[, Value := stringr::str_replace_all(Value, " ", "_")][]
dcast(df, PMID ~ Variable, toString, value.var = "Value")
```

> ```
>    PMID                            MH                 RN
> 1:    1     Humans, Male, Middle_Aged Aldosterone, Renin
> 2:    2      Accidents,_Traffic, Male         Antivenins
> 3:    3 Humans, Crotulus, Young_Adult
> ```

#### Data

```
df <- readr::read_table(
 "PMID          Variable         Value
  1             MH               Humans
  1             MH               Male
  1             MH               Middle Aged
  1             RN               Aldosterone
  1             RN               Renin
  2             MH               Accidents, Traffic
  2             MH               Male
  2             RN               Antivenins
  3             MH               Humans
  3             MH               Crotulus
  3             MH               Young Adult"
)
```